# Add values of multiple fields from one table and subtract it to a field from another table in php

Tags: php, addition, subtraction

I have two tables : `contract` `bill`. 
`contract` table contains following fields(contId (PK), contractNumber, quantity, etc..). 
`bill` contains following fields(billId (PK), billNo, contId, checkMtr, etc...).

Here every contract can have multiple bills. What I am trying to do is `add` all the `inwMtr` of a contract and deduct that from the `quantity` and display the final mtrs as Pending Mtr.

Here is what I have tried:

```
<?php

include("dbconnection.php");

$sql1 = mysql_query("SELECT quantity FROM contract WHERE contId = '25'");
while($result1  = mysql_fetch_array($sql1))
{
//echo "$result1[quantity]";
//echo "<br/>";


//echo "<br/>";

$sql2 = mysql_query("SELECT checkMtr FROM bill WHERE contId = '25'");
while($result2  = mysql_fetch_array($sql2))
{
//echo "$result2[checkMtr]";
//echo "<br/>";

$a = $result1['quantity'] - $result2['checkMtr'];
echo "$a";
echo "<br/>";

}
echo "<br/>";

}
echo "<br/>";
?>
```

Here it does subtract checkMtr from quantity but it does it for every bill. It doesn't add checkmtrs of all the bills and then subtract.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why should it? You're not doing anything that adds them up. Maybe you should use `sum(checkMtr)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$sql2 = mysql_query("SELECT sum(checkMtr) checkMtr FROM bill WHERE contId = '25'");
if (mysql_num_rows($sql2) == 1) {
  $result2  = mysql_fetch_array($sql2);
  $a = $result1['quantity'] - $result2['checkMtr'];
} else {
  $a = $result1['quantity'];
}
echo $a;
```

There's also no need for the `while` loop after the first query. It can never return more than one row, since you're selecting the row by primary key.

You can also combine this into one query:

```
SELECT quantity - ifnull(sum(checkMtr), 0) result
FROM contract c
LEFT JOIN bill USING (contId)
WHERE c.contId = '25'
```

To do this for all contracts, use `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT c.contId, quantity - ifnull(sum(checkMtr), 0) result
FROM contract c
LEFT JOIN bill USING (contId)
GROUP BY c.contId
```

[SQLFIDDLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/947e2/1)

Comment: See the new query that gets the final result in one step.

Comment: but what if i want this for all the contracts?? I mean without any conditions?

Comment: this is not working...it gives me all the quantity, but does not do the subtraction.

Comment: Working for me, see the fiddle

Answer (score 0):

Replace `checkMtr` both in the SQL statement and in your subtraction line with

```
SUM(checkMtr)
```

and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you want checkMtr to be a single number that is subtracted?

This will add all of the checkMtr results and will output that sum.

```
SELECT sum(checkMtr) FROM bill WHERE contId = '25'
```

Also if contId is being submitted from the user I hope you are validating the data